# TreeMap Template Framing in Java

Tags: java, templates, treemap

So, the TreeMap class in java is of the form `TreeMap<K,V>`. Obviously K needs to be a `Combarable`, but that is only checked at runtime with a cast, and if it not a `Comparable` an exception is thrown. Would it not have made more sense to define this class as `TreeMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>`?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of `TreeMap` can be given a comparator for the keys, so they do not have to have a natural total ordering.

[EDIT]

More specifically, an instance of `TreeMap` can be created by providing the constructor with an instance of `Comparator` that is capable of comparing two keys for order. If you create a map in such a way, the comparator will be used for all key comparisons. In that case, the keys wouldn't have to be inherently comparable.

Answer (score 0):

Providing key's Comparator can work.

I put key which is not Combarable in this way:

```
TreeMap<K, V> myMap = new TreeMap<K, V>(new Comparator<K>(){
    @Override
    int compare(K o1, K o2) {
       ...//Define the compare logic
    }
});

myMap.put(...);
```